# Number of solutions of a polynomial over finite fields

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, polynomials, finite-fields

Consider in $\mathbb{F}_q[x_1,\dots,x_n]$, where $r$ is a positive integer dividing $n$, the polynomial
$$
f(x_1,\dots,x_n)=x_1x_2\dots x_r+x_{r+1}x_{r+2}\dots x_{2r}+\dots+x_{n-r+1}x_{n-r+2}x_{n}.
$$
What is the cardinality of the set of the solutions to $f(x_1,\dots,x_n)=0$?

Bonus question:

and if $n\neq 0\mod{r}$, so that the last monomial of $f$ has less than $r$ variables multiplied?

Edit: 
$f(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is the product of the first $r$ variables plus the product of the second r variables and so on (so it is of degree one in each variable, with total degree $r$).

It is clear that imposing a variable in each monomial to be zero then the set of the solutions has at least size around $q^{(r-1)n/r}r-n/r+1$, but my question arises from the fact that I don't know what is the actual size of this set (it is not difficult to find some solutions having $x_i\ne0$, for all $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$).

Comment: Anyway, I would begin unravelling this by trying to solve for $x_n$ in terms of the others (assuming that my guess of $x_n$ appearing in a single term only is correct). When can you solve for it? What if you cannot?

Comment: This can become an interesting question. I'm sure you can improve it, either with pointers from  [our guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619) or possibly getting something going using my comments as hints. Mind you, such comments may easily misfire (I'm prepared for that as I didn't think this through as some clarifications are needed) , but I wanted to share my first thoughts in the hope that you can make some progresss yourself!

Comment: Thank you for the comments, I edited explaining better the problem. Unfortunately I don't have a general guess on the behaviour of this number.

Comment: Much improved, good job! Hope you enjoy MSE!

Comment: My current guess is that a formula for the number of solutions can be derived with the following ideas. Consider the product $P=x_1x_2\cdots x_r$. It is clearly non-zero for $(q-1)^r$ choices of $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_r)$. Therefore $P=0$ for 
$q^r-(q-1)^r$ choices. Equally clearly $P$ takes all non-zero values equally often, so for a chosen $z\in\Bbb{F}_q^*$ we have $P=z$ for $(q-1)^{r-1}$ inputs.

Comment: (cont'd) Consider then the case with $n=kr$. Let $N(k)$ be the number of solutions. If the first $k-1$ products of $r$ variables sum up to zero ($N(k-1)$ ways), then the last product must also be zero ($q^r-(q-1)^r$ ways). If the first $k-1$ don't sum up to zero ($q^{(k-1)r}-N(k-1)$ ways), then the last product must have a fixed non-zero value ($(q-1)^{r-1}$ ways). So we have a recursive formula:
$$N(k)=N(k-1)(q^r-(q-1)^{r-1})+(q^{(k-1)r}-N(k-1))(q-1)^{r-1}.$$ I don't know if it is easy to show what this leads to. A different approach may work better.

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Yes, you are right! 
I think that there's a typo in your formula and the actual number is $$N(k)=N(k-1)(q^r-(q-1)^r)+(q^{(k-1)r}-N(k-1))(q-1)^{r-1}$$

Comment: Thank you, I will think about finding another way to have the explicit formula, but this is a very good point

Comment: Oops. Good job catching the typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My previous attempt having failed due to dependence between the terms (see edit history if you want to laugh and point), I think the best approach is to see this as a Markov process over prefixes of the sum, with two states: zero and non-zero.

Let $n = rs$.

There are $q^r$ possibilities for each term, of which $(q-1)^r$ are non-zero, distributed evenly over the $q-1$ non-zero field elements. Therefore the number you want is $$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}q^r - (q-1)^r & (q-1)^{r-1} \\ (q-1)^r & q^r - (q-1)^{r-1}\end{bmatrix}^s
\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$$
The transition matrix diagonalises (I used a CAS) as $$\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{q-1} & -1 \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}q^r & 0 \\ 0 & q^r - q(q-1)^{r-1}\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}\frac{q-1}{q} & \frac{q-1}{q} \\ \frac{1-q}{q} & \frac{1}{q} \end{bmatrix}
$$
so we get
$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{q-1} & -1 \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}q^r & 0 \\ 0 & q^r - q(q-1)^{r-1}\end{bmatrix}^s
\begin{bmatrix}\frac{q-1}{q} & \frac{q-1}{q} \\ \frac{1-q}{q} & \frac{1}{q} \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix} \\
=
\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{q-1} & -1 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}q^n & 0 \\ 0 & [q^r - q(q-1)^{r-1}]^s\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}\frac{q-1}{q} \\ \frac{1-q}{q} \end{bmatrix} \\
=
q^{n-1} + q^{s-1}(q-1)[q^{r-1} - (q-1)^{r-1}]^s
$$

---

For the bonus question, let $n = rs + t$ with $0 < t < r$. Then we take the same transition matrix, substituting $t$ for $r$, and apply to the previous result to get $$
\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}q^t - (q-1)^t & (q-1)^{t-1} \\ (q-1)^t & q^t - (q-1)^{t-1}\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}q^{rs-1} + q^{s-1}(q-1)[q^{r-1} - (q-1)^{r-1}]^s \\ q^{rs} - q^{rs-1} - q^{s-1}(q-1)[q^{r-1} - (q-1)^{r-1}]^s\end{bmatrix} \\
= [q^t - (q-1)^t][q^{rs-1} + q^{s-1}(q-1)[q^{r-1} - (q-1)^{r-1}]^s] + [(q-1)^{t-1}][q^{rs} - q^{rs-1} - q^{s-1}(q-1)[q^{r-1} - (q-1)^{r-1}]^s] \\
= q^{rs} (q-1)^{t-1} + [q^t - q(q-1)^{t-1}][q^{rs-1} + q^{s-1}(q-1)[q^{r-1} - (q-1)^{r-1}]^s] \\
= q^{n-1} + q^s(q-1)[q^{t-1} - (q-1)^{t-1}][q^{r-1} - (q-1)^{r-1}]^s
$$

---

In fact, there's enough structure there to conjecture and prove that for a general  composition of $n$, $\lambda_1 + \cdots + \lambda_k = n$, the number of solutions of $$x_1x_2\cdots x_{\lambda_1}+x_{\lambda_1+1}x_{\lambda_1+2}\cdots x_{\lambda_1 + \lambda_2}+\cdots = 0$$ is given by $$q^{n-1} + q^{k-1}(q-1)\prod_{i=1}^k [q^{\lambda_i-1} - (q-1)^{\lambda_i-1}]$$

By induction on $k$.

If $k=1$ we have the original problem with $r=\lambda_1, s=k=1$.

If it holds for $k$ then for $k+1$ we have $$
\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}q^{\lambda_{k+1}} - (q-1)^{\lambda_{k+1}} & (q-1)^{\lambda_{k+1}-1} \\ (q-1)^{\lambda_{k+1}} & q^{\lambda_{k+1}} - (q-1)^{\lambda_{k+1}-1}\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}q^{n - \lambda_{k+1}-1} + q^{k-1}(q-1)\prod_{i=1}^k [q^{\lambda_i-1} - (q-1)^{\lambda_i-1}] \\ q^{n - \lambda_{k+1}} - q^{n - \lambda_{k+1}-1} - q^{k-1}(q-1)\prod_{i=1}^k [q^{\lambda_i-1} - (q-1)^{\lambda_i-1}]\end{bmatrix} \\
= [q^{\lambda_{k+1}} - (q-1)^{\lambda_{k+1}}][q^{n - \lambda_{k+1}-1} + q^{k-1}(q-1)\prod_{i=1}^k [q^{\lambda_i-1} - (q-1)^{\lambda_i-1}]] + [(q-1)^{\lambda_{k+1}-1}][q^{n - \lambda_{k+1}} - q^{n - \lambda_{k+1}-1} - q^{k-1}(q-1)\prod_{i=1}^k [q^{\lambda_i-1} - (q-1)^{\lambda_i-1}]] \\
= q^{n-1} + q^k (q-1) \prod_{i=1}^{k+1} [q^{\lambda_i-1} - (q-1)^{\lambda_i-1}]
$$
as desired.

Comment: "If we take the final non-zero term, its value is fixed by the previous ones, which are free and independent" they aren't independent since they can't sum to zero.

Comment: Good point. Back to the drawing board...

Comment: I've completely rewritten the answer.